# Compare rows of same panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare rows which are in same group. Suppose I have a dataframe like below -

| ind | SID | SEMID | TID | TYP | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 450 | A | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 451 | A | 9 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 452 | A | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 455 | A | 2 |

Here you can see ind number 0, 1, 2 are in same group (as the SID, SEMID, TYP are same). So from this group I want to only the row which has highest value of P (15).
My expected output dataframe would be like below.

| ind | SID | SEMID | TID | TYP | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 452 | A | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 455 | A | 2 |

How can I achieve this in python?
I am totally  new to Python. It would be helpful if any expert help on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `groupby` + `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['SID', 'SEMID', 'TYP']).P.idxmax()]

   ind  SID  SEMID  TID TYP   P
3    3    1      3  455   A   2
2    2    1      5  452   A  15
```